# directory or site specific php.ini directives with php and iis 6+

Tags: php, windows, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

As stated [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.windows), you can't easily modify php ini values labeled `PHP_INI_PERDIR` when running PHP with IIS.

Is there any way to provide similar functionality on a per-site or per-directory basis for [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) settings that can't be set using `ini_set()` or that aren't `PHP_INI_USER` (and thus can't be set in the Windows registry - which seems like a terrible place to put ini settings anyhow)?

Answer (score 0):

Similar functionality actually does exist - if you're using php 5.3+.

You can easily edit your php.ini and add entries similar to the following per each site you want to modify at the end of your existing php.ini file:

```
[PATH=C:/code/website1.com/]
upload_max_filesize = 2M

[PATH=C:/code/website2.com/]
upload_max_filesize = 12M
```